# Issues with freshly installed windows

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10

Yesterday i encountered `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` blue screen error

[image]

So i performed a clean install(Formated c drive and reinstalled os) then today

When i start my pc it shows Recovery error

[image]

1. Try again shows same error
2. f8 does do anything screen blinks and same screen come back

So i created Windows Bootable Media to repair or Reinstall windows But after loading files screen goes black and nothing shows up...

Same for booting in safe mode , low resolution mode.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you installing in a HDD?

Comment: @vembutech Yeap

Comment: Boot from Hiren cd and run check disk. If your HDD have any bad sector it show you.